# VBA to move records from one table to another

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I want to move records from Table Sheet2 to Table Sheet3. I am getting error as

> operation cannot be performed when object is open.

```
With Acon
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + myFileNameDir
    .Open
End With

With Rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .ActiveConnection = Acon
    .Source = "Select * from [Sheet2] where [Manager Com]= 'OK'"
    .Open
End With

With Rs1
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .ActiveConnection = Acon
    .Source = "Select * from [Sheet3]"
    .Open
End With

Dim strSQL  As String
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Sheet3 SELECT * From Sheet2 where [Manager Com]= 'OK'"
Rs.Open strSQL

Rs1.Close
Rs.Close
Acon.Close

Set Rs = Nothing
Set Acon = Nothing
```

Comment: Seeing your old questions you are doing the same kind of mistakes for the code formatting. Please use the `{ }` option in the markdown editor to format the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you are trying to execute a statement from a query.
Try the following:

```
Dim CMD As Object
Dim strSQL  As String

With Acon
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + myFileNameDir
    .Open
End With

Set CMD = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
CMD.ActiveConnection = ACon


strSQL = "INSERT INTO Sheet3 SELECT * From Sheet2 where [Manager Com]= 'OK'"

CMD.CommandText = strSQL
CMD.Execute

Acon.Close
```